# Node JS / Hapi image upload and security

Tags: node.js, image, security, upload, hapi.js

Like many webservices, we need to get our visitors' profile picture. This is done through a simple hapi upload script.

We are now wondering what are the best practices to prevent us from getting a malicious image that could contain a script to be executed directly or through a vulnerability.

What is the best secure process ? Resizing the image ? But what about the several formats available ? Convert everything to PNG in a two-step pass using two different libraries ?

Is there any npm written for that purpose ?

Advises needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit for working code in github https://github.com/pandeysoni/Hapi-file-upload-download

```
/*
 * upload file
 */

exports.uploadFile = {
    payload: {
        maxBytes: 209715200,
        output: 'stream',
        parse: false
    },
    handler: function(requset, reply) {
        var form = new multiparty.Form();
        form.parse(requset.payload, function(err, fields, files) {
            if (err) return reply(err);
            else upload(files, reply);
        });
    }
};

/*
 * upload file function
 */

var upload = function(files, reply) {
    fs.readFile(files.file[0].path, function(err, data) {
        checkFileExist();
        fs.writeFile(Config.MixInsideFolder + files.file[0].originalFilename, data, function(err) {
            if (err) return reply(err);
            else return reply('File uploaded to: ' + Config.MixInsideFolder + files.file[0].originalFilename);

        });
    });
};
```